# Can abstract models for solving NP-hard problems be built in reality?

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory, computational-geometry, computation-theory

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.613.6143&rep=rep1&type=pdf) proofs, that NP-hard problems can be solved efficiently through abstract geometrical computations. These computations are based on signals, which are dimensionless and can move uniformly on a hypothetical *real* axis in time and space.

The authors claim the model to be only abstract and

> *...with no apriori ambition to be physically realizable.*

In fact, [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00079720/document) shows, that the practical limitation is due to the need for a *black hole* to absorb emerging limit points within calculations.

Actually, there exist several black hole analogues and the first one was created in 2009, based on a rubidium Bose–Einstein condensate using a technique called density inversion (1). A further method by lasing the phonons also detected self-amplifying Hawking radiation in 2014 (2).

**Can such analogues of black holes be used to build the signal machines described above? In effect, such a machine could be able to solve NP-complete problems efficiently.**

If not, what exactly are the physically limitations for building such signal machines. If it could be possible to built them, what would be the implications for complex theory and the N versus NP Problem?

---

(1) Lahav, et. al. "Realization of a sonic black hole analogue in a Bose-Einstein condensate", 2009 (see doi: 10.1103/PhysRevLett.105.240401)

(2) J. Steinhauer, "Observation of self-amplifying Hawking radiation in an analogue black-hole laser", 2014 (see doi:10.1038/nphys3104)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another StackExchange site.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for cstheory StackExchange, or perhaps Physics StackExchange. From my limited understanding, this question is akin to positing an oracle that makes P=NP, and then asking if the oracle physically exists. I think the answer has to be that we simply don't know. We can imagine this oracle, and use it to show its affect on computational complexity, but like all oracles (like, for instance, one for solving the halting problem) we simply don't know whether there is one. We have a candidate here - black holes - but we don't know if they really have the properties we ...

Comment: ... need, or if the properties we think they have are actually subtly different in a way that makes the proof physically impossible, or if there are other physical limitations. That this might work is more likely than, e.g., finding a magic lamp and getting a genie to solve NP-Hard problems in polynomial time, but the difference is quantitative (probability) not qualitative (both are "possible" in some sense). And if it does exist - it doesn't change the question P=NP for Turing machines, as presently defined; it just might make it less important if we can extend it to include these oracles.

Comment: As models for computation get closer to the true mathematics of nature it would make sense to eventually find one that *is* nature (assuming mathematics is at the bottom of it all). First of all such a model would represent a grand unifying theory of everything that reconciles quantum mechanics with relativity. Second, it's not clear that such a model would necessarily lend itself to every problem in NP unless every problem in NP can also be "built in reality" so to speak.

Comment: If I am right, the claimed method uses a computing device with unlimited (or high) computing power, making many things possible. This has no impact on the P/NP conjecture, which pertains to sequential computation.